# Is there a way within a link to make a page and a popup open in sequence and in the same tab?

Tags: html, href, window.open

I am pretty new to html and want to find a way to set up a single link to do the following when clicked once:

1. Open a given page
2. Open a second link (a popup) in the context of the page

This for an ecommerce platform that I don't have any backend access to, so I can't mess around with any functions.

I have so far cobbled together some tests, but all seem to open new tabs. I would want it to open in the same tab to have the second link (a popup) open on top of the page opened first.

I have tried things like:

```
<a href="#"
     onclick=" window.open('page 1 link');
               window.open('popup link');" target="_top"
               >Click Here</a>
```

and

```
<a href="page 1 link" onclick="window.open('popup link');
      return false;">multiopen</a>
```

Just kind of stabbing in the dark here.

They all open two separate tabs.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
    <p><a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://dummy.com');
    window.open('http://dummy2.com');">Click to open 2 pages</a></p>
```

If you want one of the link is to be opened on the same tab, put the first link to `href` and second link to `window.open()`function.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried that and it's still opening two separate tabs.

Comment: <p><a href="www.link1.com" onclick="window.open('www.link2.com');
  </a></p>            did you try this?

Comment: Sorry for delay. Yes I tried that and it opens the first link in the same tab, second link in a new tab. I would need that second link to be in the same tab.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not get the point, what is your purpose?

Comment: Sorry... I don't get notifications it seems. My point was that I want the URLs to open sequentially in the same tab. I am trying to link to an ecommerce site that opens products in popup windows only. So the normal flow is that a user would browse and then open a product. This product opens in a popup and thus the context of their browsing remains intact. They close the popup and they are still at the same place in the list of products. So I would want the click to open URL 1 in a tab, then URL 2 in the same tab (URL 2 will open as a popup in the platform).